# Hello, I need to create a python query that select a maximum and minimum value in every row of the selected columns

Tags: python, mysql-workbench

For instance in the first row,(Afghanistan) the query should compare the rates of PCCW,ALLIPTELECOM_PREMIUM, ALLIPTELECOM STANDARD, BICS_BC and BICS_FC and the record both the min and the max rate,,and then state the provider with the maximum rate and the provider with the minimum rate.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BWmN.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also please give a proper description of your environment and data model.

Comment: imported the csv file into mysql workbench, created python connection to the database, and am stuck at querying

Answer (score 0):

Convert the datasheet to csv or export it and then you can use pandas dataframe that will find the maximum rates/ minimum rates

then you can use the following code:

```
df[minimum_rate] = Afganistan.min()
df[maximum_rate] = Afganistan.max()
```

There are plenty of library to connect to mysql. eg.
SQLalchemy,mysql.connector.etc.
Here's one tutorial from w3school:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp

Comment: You answer requires a rather heavy dependency for something that a database (I suspect Mysql because of the tag) can do on its own.

Comment: I have already created the connection using mysql connector. I am stuck at creating the queries